# What is the recommended document structure for front end development?

Tags: html, model-view-controller, frontend

What is the most coherent directory structure followed by the community for the front end (HTML) development? There are lot of factors to be considered like easy updating and maintenance, ease in back end integration, which would follow MVC pattern.

Explanation regarding the same is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are folders that I have

`/css/` for style sheets 
 
`/img/` for images 
 
`/js/` for javascript files 
 
`/template/` for template files e.g. headers, footers 
 
`/script/` for scripts and functions (I use PHP so for my php files) 
 
`/inc/` any include files (flash etc.) 
 
`/lang/` for language packs (if you have any)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there is necessarily a structure but I like to do this:

_assets/images
_assets/css
_assets/js
_assets/flash
_assets/pdf